# Pushing an Array element into an existing multidimensional array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a query in codeigniter like this

```
$query_tutors = $this->db->get_where("tutor_info", array('tutor_id' => $tutor_id));
```

I have also other array elements that I want to pass in the query which depends on some conditions.

So how do I push other multidimensional array elements to the existing array so I can pass the variable as a whole in the query?

array_push is not working in this case.

```
$array = array();
$array = array("tutor_id" => $tutor_id);
$array = array("online" => $online);  // want to merge this to the 1st array.

$query_tutors = $this->db->get_where("tutor_info", $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you're doing it wrong.

```
$array = array();
$array = array("tutor_id" => $tutor_id);
```

You're recreating the array again, which will delete it from the memory. Either you have to use

```
$array['tutor_id'] = $tutor_id; 
$array["online"]   = $online;
```

or

```
$array = array('tutor_id' => $tutor_id, 'online' => $online);
```

or if you want to merge two arrays

```
$array = array_merge(array('tutor_id' => $tutor_id), array('tutor_id' => $tutor_id));
```

Comment: `array_merge` sounds to me that is what he is looking for

Comment: `array_merge` is not going to help in since he wants to add array elements based on some conditions. so adding 1 element at a time will help him.

Comment: `array_merge` will definitely help. The `get_where` method accepts an array. By merging the arrays (which he probably builds in different controllers with different information and levels), he can pass it to the `get_where` method dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code

```
$array = [];
$array = ["tutor_id" => $tutor_id];
```

Now, if you want to add conditional merge, simply follow,

```
if($condition)
{
    $array = array_merge($array, ["online" => $online]);
}
```

If `$condition == true` You final array will be,

```
$array = ['tutor_id' => $tutor_id, 'online' => $online];
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there, just need to read a little bit more about associative arrays.

Solution:

```
$array = array();
$array["tutor_id"] = $tutor_id;
$array["online"]   = $online;
$query_tutors = $this->db->get_where("tutor_info", $array);
```

This way your `$array` will have all indexes which you want.

You can do something like this:

```
$array = array();

if (!empty($tutor_id))
{
    $array["tutor_id"] = $tutor_id;
}

if (!empty($online))
{
    $array["online"] = $online;
}
$query_tutors = $this->db->get_where("tutor_info", $array);
```

Comment: this is not what he is asking for

Comment: basically because he is asking how to merge two arrays together, and you are not providing that answer.

Comment: @CodeGodie  `array_merge` is one of the way to do it. But we can achieve the same functionality using the snippet above since he just wants to add new elements in the array.

Comment: ok, I actually see the OP changed his question. They initially asked "how to merge" specifically, and now it says "how do I push other multidimensional". Because of that, your answer now applies.

Comment: Thanks :) .... You had given a down vote to the answer. Is it possible to revert that? If yes then plz do it else it is fine .. @CodeGodie